# How to remove repeated items?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to remove the repeated items that come from a table in the database.
I tried to create two lists that receive the same values and compare but it didn’t work, could you show me a way?

```java
@GetMapping( "consulta/{id_empresa}/{tipo_tarifa}" )
ArrayList<ResultadosDTO> listarResultadosPorTarifa( @PathVariable( "id_empresa" ) Integer id_empresa, @PathVariable( "tipo_tarifa" ) String tipo_tarifa ) {
        
        List<Resultados> resultados = repository.listarResultadosPorTarifa(id_empresa, tipo_tarifa);
        
        //System.out.println(resultados.size()); <- Aqui ele mostra a quantidade elementos armazenados na variável resultados
        
        ArrayList<ResultadosDTO> ConjuntoResultados = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ResultadosDTO> lista = new ArrayList<>(); // Criando uma segunda lsita que tambem vai receber os valores e serão comparados para excluir os repetidos
        for ( int i=0; i<resultados.size(); i++ )
        {
            ResultadosDTO r = new ResultadosDTO();
            r.setId(resultados.get(i).getId());
            r.setId_empresa(resultados.get(i).getId_empresa());
            r.setId_unidade(resultados.get(i).getId_unidade());
            r.setTipo_tarifa(resultados.get(i).getTipo_tarifa());
            r.setAno(resultados.get(i).getAno());
            r.setMensal(resultados.get(i).getMensal());
            r.setAnual(resultados.get(i).getAnual());
            r.setPorcentagem(resultados.get(i).getPorcentagem());
            
            ConjuntoResultados.add(r);
            lista.add(r);
            
            //System.out.println(lista);
            
        }

        return ConjuntoResultados;
        
}
```

Comment: What constitutes a "repeated item" in this case?

Comment: Which database you are using? Are you using an ORM like Spring Data JPA? If so you could query as something starting with 'findDistinct..()' or if you're using the JDBC you can create a SQL query.

Give more details, please. You can share your repository and service classes.

Comment: My database is PostgreSQL and I am using Spring Data JPA.

Comment: I am creating an api that returns some numeric values.

Comment: `resultados = resultados.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())`
Does this solve your problem, or is this what you want the result to look like?

Comment: It didn't work... My response is like this:
id = 1
year = 1
value = 100

Each unity has only 5 years so I receive this data repeated 3 times because another script is inserting 5 times.

Comment: Can you add more detail about how your data structure with some records and your expected result?

Comment: I got a solution using: 
select distinct id_unidade, mensal, anual, porcentagem from resultados where id_empresa = 176 and tipo_tarifa='verde';

But I cannot use it because my repository is like this:
@Query(value="select * from result where id_empresa = :id_empresa and tipo_tarifa= :tipo_tarifa", nativeQuery=true)
 List<Resultados> listarResultadosPorTarifa( @Param( "id_empresa" ) Integer id_empresa, @Param( "tipo_tarifa" ) String tipo_tarifa );

If I use it I got an error: id column is not in resultset